# Athena latest JDBC driver jar AthenaJDBC42_2.0.14

Tags: jdbc, amazon-athena, mulesoft

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html
I've installed latest jdbc jar into my local mvn repo. While i'm trying to build my project I'm getting below error.

```
Failed to collect dependencies at Athena:AthenaJDBC42:jar:2.0.14.1000: Failed to read artifact descriptor for Athena:AthenaJDBC42:jar:2.0.14.1000: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for Athena:AthenaJDBC${env.JDBC_V}:${env.MAJOR_V}.${env.MINOR_V}.${env.REVISION_V}.${env.BUILD_V}
[ERROR] [ERROR] 'artifactId' with value 'AthenaJDBC${env.JDBC_V}' does not match a valid id pattern. @
```

Anyone have any idea, how to resolve this error.?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say with just the small Maven error snippet, but it looks like Maven doesn't recognize the property ${env.JDBC_V} or it contains some invalid value like a space.

I recommend to generate a Maven effective pom model (`mvn help~effective-pom`) and execute Maven in debug mode (`mvn -X ...`) to try to troubleshoot the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. It got resolved when I installed jar into repository using following command. (Ensure you deleted all existing instances of athena drivers jar files from .m2 before executing command)

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/chetanparekh/Downloads/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.14.jar -DgroupId=Athena -DartifactId=AthenaJDBC42 -Dversion=2.0.14.1000 -Dpackaging=jar

Snippet from my POM.

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
            <sharedLibraries>
                    <sharedLibrary>
                        <groupId>Athena</groupId>
                        <artifactId>AthenaJDBC42</artifactId>
                    </sharedLibrary>
                </sharedLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>Athena</groupId>
        <artifactId>AthenaJDBC42</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14.1000</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
I finally resolved it using
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/dk/Downloads/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.14.jar -DgroupId=Athena -DartifactId=AthenaJDBC42 -Dversion=2.0.14

Removed the build version(1000) and -Dpackaing=jar, it worked. I'm not sure what could be the problem with build version .1000 and -Dpacking=jar.

Thanks Again.!